# hperlink not getting embedded or correctly read in angular UI

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Currently I am reading text from json and displaying it in angular UI. I need to add hyperlink though but it seems like the its not understanding anchor tag.

This is how the rendered page looks

```
1.3 If you do not agree to any of the provisions of these Terms, you should immediately stop using the Portal. If you have any questions regarding these Terms, you can contact us as set out in paragraph 12 below. 
1.4 Please also read our Privacy Policy <a href='https://www.test.com/site-services/privacy-policy'</a>  and how we use cookies in providing the Portal.
```

Html page

```
 <section>
  <article class="info-panel">
        <!-- <object data="assets/terms_of_use.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object> -->
        <p class="terms" *ngIf="readOnline">
          {{ 'portal.onboarding.welcome.stage1.terms_full' | translate }}
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
```

json

```
  "terms_full": "\r\n If you do not agree to any of the provisions of these Terms, you should immediately stop using the Portal. If you have any questions regarding these Terms, you can contact us as set out in paragraph 12 below. \r\n1.4\tPlease also read our Privacy Policy <a href='https://www.test.com/site-services/privacy-policy'</a> and how we use cookies in providing the Portal.\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[innerHTML]` attribute.

```
<section>
  <article class="info-panel">
    <p class="terms" *ngIf="readOnline"  [innerHTML]="'portal.onboarding.welcome.stage1.terms_full' | translate"></p>
  </article>
</section>
```

**NOTE:** You also didn't close `<a>` tag in your `JSON` file, so you should also do that.

```
"terms_full": "\r\n If you do not agree to any of the provisions of these Terms, you should immediately stop using the Portal. If you have any questions regarding these Terms, you can contact us as set out in paragraph 12 below. \r\n1.4\tPlease also read our Privacy Policy <a href='https://www.test.com/site-services/privacy-policy'></a> and how we use cookies in providing the Portal.\r\n"
```

Comment: got this error Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{ 'portal.onboarding.welcome.stage1.terms_full' | translate }}] in

Comment: I can see you have added an extra > at the end. I have removed it and now it compiles but however the text does not appear as link.its just the same as before

Comment: I  now can actually see that you have included it within the para tag but it does not like it

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Also, are you using `ngx-translate`?

Comment: Yes I tried but the entire text following the a tag is being interpreted as hyperlink

Comment: In the example above the text  and how we use cookies in providing the Portal. is also interpreted as hyperlink

Comment: I need only this https://www.test.com/site-services/privacy-policy should show as hyperlink

Comment: I updated the answer again. You didn't close `<a>` tag in the `JSON` file. Can you check it?

Comment: Not sure where you see that this is what my json contains <a href='https://www.test.com/site-services/privacy-policy'</a>

Comment: I added it in answer. Try to copy it and test it again.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had already figured out my mistake. Thanks anyways. Your answer has solved my problem

Comment: I am glad you solved it. Consider also to upvote my answer if it helped you.